# How to make different objects of a class inside a function

Tags: java, object, constructor, inner-classes

I have made an inner class `in` and its constructor.

In a function `func()` I am reading two values `battery` and `time`
using a Scanner and storing them in instances of the class `in`, and this function is called multiple times.

I  want to compare the different values of `battery` entered by the user, using the class objects and then I want to print them if they match some criteria.

**I.E.**

Let's say that `func` is called 4 times with different battery values each time.

I want to check whether the difference between them is greater than 1. If yes then print that battery value.

```
1st call (98,2) 
2nd call (97,4) 
3rd call (95,9) 
4th call (94,11)
```

Here the difference between the 2nd and 3rd call's battery level is greater than 1, so I'll have to print the 2nd call's battery level and its corresponding time.

How can I code that? This is what I got:

```java
public class Out {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    class in {
        int x;
        int y;
        in(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    }

    public void func() {
        int battery = sc.nextInt();
        int time = sc.nextInt();
        in inner = new in(battery, time);
        // now i want to compare the battery values passed by user(using objects of class)
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "compare"? Compare which value to what value? How many instances of `in` should there be?

Comment: lets say func is called 4 times and i pass  different battery values each time. I want to check whether difference between them is greater then 1.. IF yes then print that battery value . Eg: 1st call- (98,2) 2nd call-(97,4) 3rd call(95,9) 4th call(94,11)  . Here difference between 2nd and 3rd call's battery level is greater than 1, so i'll have to print the initial one i.e. 2nd call battery level and its corresponding time

Answer (score 1):

A possibility could be to store the generated Objects in a List and after the func() calls you can loop through it and compare

```
List<in> storage= new LinkedList<in>();

//in the func() function:
storage.add(inner);

//after the func() calls:
for(in item : storage){
   //do your compare stuff
}
```

As hint, classnames should be capitalized ;)